# How can I check if a two strings are the same in C?

Tags: c, string, c-strings

I've just started learning **C** and I'm trying to get used to the syntax, so when I try to run the program and enter the value it doesn't return anything. I don't know what I did wrong. Can anyone help me please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char pass[10]; //max length of the string;
    do{
        printf("enter your password: \n");
        scanf("%s",pass);
    }while(strcmp(pass,'*') != 0); //checks if strings are equal

    printf("%s",pass);


}
```

Comment: Strings are enclosed in double quotes `"*"` — character constants are enclosed in single quotes `'*'`.

Comment: You compiler should be giving you a warning about `strcmp(pass,'*')`.  If it is, pay attention.  If it's not, turn on warnings.

Comment: If `pass` is declared as an array of 10 bytes, then you should change `scanf("%s",pass);` to `scanf("%9s",pass);` to avoid buffer overflows, crashes and other problems.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 4):

In C, single quotes are used for character constants.  So `'*'` is not a string containing the character `*` but *only* the character `*`.

To specify a string, use double quotes.

```
 }while(strcmp(pass,"*") != 0);
```

Comment: By the way, you will only break out of your loop if the password entered is `*`. I assume this isn't the intended behavior?

Comment: @emsimpson92 That seems to be the OP's intended behavior: stay in the loop until the user enters the correct password.

Comment: Yes, if the user entered  `*` then the loops stops and prints it out.